# How to set a default log level in log4j.properties?

Tags: java, log4j

As far as I understand it, in log4j.properties you specify what log levels to *let through* and for single cases you can restrict it further. However, I want to restrict it for all cases and be more unrestrictive in single cases. The way I tried it (see below, by setting the root logger level to error) I only get error messages but how can I express to only use ERROR as a *default level*, in case nothing else is specified?

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout

# everything else should be ERROR
org.mypackage=DEBUG
org.verbosepackage=OFF
```

**Solution**
I'm sorry, I just noticed, that I forgot the "log4j.logger." in front of the packages. With it, it really works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I do not understand, what you mean with default level. You configured LOG4J to log only error, fatal levels everywhere, except org.mypackage, where you log everything except TRACE and org.verbosepackage, where you log nothing.

Comment: The problem is that the file I showed doesn't work. It does not log debug from mypackage because root is set to error. I want error to be the DEFAULT only, changed when overwritten explicitly.

Comment: Hmm, I think that it shall work the way you like. Could not be there some other problem? For example I do not see that you specified appender for your packages. I am used to XML configuration, so it is harder for me to verify property file correctness.

Comment: Do I need more than one appender? I thought appenders are just for different output (e.g. file vs command line).

Comment: You can set, where each category shall go and you can even combine output to multiple logs. But you assigned logger for root logger, so it shall be OK.

Comment: you can use a special appender for your package with desired level.

Comment: Well, congratulation. I prefer XML configuration, so I did not notice missing prefix.